# Controlar conexión a base de datos desde página html. Recursos mínimos. ¿Cómo?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, aplicación-web

El asunto es el siguiente:

Tengo una base de datos en LibreOffice Base 5.1, a la cual diferentes usuarios *deben* tener acceso.

Tengo Notepad++.

Tengo acceso a una carpeta compartida por los usuarios mencionados anteriormente.

Y ya está. No tengo más recursos que esto. No puedo instalar más nada.

Puedo *descargar* otras cosas (en tanto no requieran llamar a programas terceros por ningún motivo), pero no puedo *instalar* nada, y tengo que hacer posible que se conecten los usuarios con diferentes niveles de permisos.

Al principio usé [esta](http://wiki.open-office.es/Gestion_de_permisos_de_usuario_en_OpenOffice_Base) guía (muy útil, por cierto) y todo bien hasta que me doy cuenta del riesgo que es dejar el archivo ahí sin más.

Probé manipulando directamente los permisos del *"sa"* de Base y creando algunos usuarios, organizando sus permisos y tal, pero nada de eso impedía que las *tablas* se pudieran eliminar, o hacerse nuevas por un usuario cualquiera.

Probé utilizando el macro para ventana de inicio de sesión, pero eso se puede superar con apenas desactivar los macros.

Así que estoy optando por hacer un sitio web local a través del cual se puedan ingresar o solicitar datos hacia o desde la base de datos, pero... no tengo idea de cómo!

Empecé haciendo una pagina de inicio de sesión en html, pero pero a medida que iba escribiendo me iban surgiendo cada vez más dudas:

*"Ok, ¿dónde se van a guardar los usuarios y contraseñas?", "cómo programo la interfaz?, "cómo hago que se conecte a la base de datos y ésta esté siempre disponible?", "podré usar la carpeta compartida como si fuera un servidor?"*

Y bueno, la verdad me ha dado bastante trabajo ir investigando cosa por cosa, pero es que aún no me cuaja nada, todas las soluciones que he encontrado implican utilizar algún otro programa, y eso no lo puedo hacer.

**Sólo puedo usar Notepad++ y LibreOffice Base 5.1**

*edit: se valen todos los lenguajes de programación disponibles en Notepad++, en tanto no requieran de compilador ni viole las otras condiciones.*

edit 2: El punto es:

***¿Cómo puedo dar acceso, a través de un sitio web html local, a diferentes usuarios con diferentes niveles de permiso a una base de datos, de modo que ciertos puedan hacer ciertas cosas, y otros, otras?***

Comment: Lindo Reto......

Comment: Con PHP... ya está hecho, pero ¿dices que no puedes usar PHP? Por cierto, ¿qué sentido tiene la etiqueta php en la pregunta? HTML es un editor de textos con etiquetado, si quieres hacer cosas más potentes **y seguras sobre todo** tendrás que combinarlo con un lenguaje de programación.

Comment: Pues, puedo escribir en cualquier lenguaje en tanto no necesite un compilador, ni viole las reglas que mencioné en la pregunta.

Comment: El objetivo principal no lo entiendo, no sé cuál es.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que...

Puedes habilitar el IIS que viene por defecto en la máquina que utilizarías como servidor web. Ahí pondrías tu interfaz de usuario (html/php si lo soporta) y un web service el cual se encargaría de las consultas a la bd.

Utilizarías AJAX (Javascript) desde tu interfaz de usuario hacia ese web service que menciono.

Para el lado del servidor (el web service), no necesitas más que 4 archivos que puedes crear en cualquier editor de texto (Yo tengo una solución implementada de ésta manera). **TEN EN CUENTA** que ésto supone habilidad tuya para escribir código en **C#** y que ya conoces más o menos cómo configurar un sitio web en IIS ya que básicamente estarás escribiendo a ciegas! (no habrá nada que te guíe, ni te dirá si tienes errores en los nombres, algún paréntesis faltante, errores en tipo de datos, variables no inicializadas, librerías no importadas, métodos inalcanzables y un montón de posibles errores más).

Si puedes codificar éstos archivos desde otra máquina con Visual Studio y sólo copiarlo al servidor web te ayudará mucho.

Los archivos son de un web service WCF

- Web.config  (XML)
- MiServicio.svc (XML)
- Carpeta App_Code

  - IServicio.cs (código C#, lo puedes abrir con Notepad++ )
  - Servicio.svc.cs (código C#, editable)

En el Web.config te recomiendo que habilites mostrar las excepciones en el navgador con `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>` . Te ayudará a saber qué errores encontró el IIS en tu web service.

Comment: Vale, lo intentaré y luego comento cómo me fue